# Unit testing in Visual Studio for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unit-tests

Original question (now deleted) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382025/unit-testing-in-visual-studio-for-javascript)

I am searching a good tool for JavaScript unit testing. I am using Visual Studio as the IDE. Please recommend me a VS add-on for that.

Also if possible point me to the tutorial on how to use that plugin.

I already tried [this link](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/12/01/javascript-unit-testing-with-visual-studio.aspx).

I used Chutzpah; it is simple not detecting my test cases or load them to the Test Explorer. Every time I had to manually go and run it. I used it with Qunit 1.4; ReSharper on the other hand is not free.

Comment: Please explain more context. What platforms are you targeting? Test tools are sometimes very tied to platforms, maybe even more than implementation languages.

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio, I think Resharper might be the best-in-class. Do some calculations, maybe it's worth its price for you.

I'm using VSCode and there's good integrations for most big tools, like jest, mocha, chai, and more.